# How to make ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb smaller?

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I customize scrollbar by CSS3. And I don't know, how to make scrollbar-thumb smaller (shorter). Width or height don't work. Can anybody help me?

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#child {
  width: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #8c1b21;
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #B79889;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #8c1b21;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Height of thumb depends on the height of the `div` where you are applying `scroll`

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#child {
  width: 250px;
  height: 4000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #8c1b21;
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #B79889;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #8c1b21;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I know that, but I don't need to make my div bigger - I only need to make scrollbar-thumb smaller.

Comment: It is not possible, have you seen any of the OS windows or any websites with that type of scroll? with the help of scroll thumb we can know that the page height

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a lot of methods for this very problem; the usual answer is create a div, make a custom scroll bar (don't), or don't bother. This is a solution I found previously to solve this problem:

```
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
```

Basically surround the track with transparent thicc borders, ie. shorten the track.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, "::-webkit-scrollbar /width" is the key

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 4px !important;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  background-color: $apple-gray;
}
```